# Azure - Any ways to have common cache between two App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have two App Service hosted:

1) Service (WebAPi).
2) WebJobs.

Is there anyway a common cache can be shared between two. Looking for options other than Azure Redis Cache.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use Azure Redis Cache?

Comment: well, use redis on a vm. i dont get it. whats wrong with redis? use any other cache for that matter